# If statement for structure

Tags: c, if-statement, structure

I have to write if statement for structure for person which:

Is older or equal 16 and younger or equal 20
First letter of name and surname must be 's' or 'n'

My code:

```
if(x.name[0]=='s' ||
   x.name[0]=='n' &&
   x.surname[0]=='s' ||
   x.surname[0]=='n' &&
   (x.age>=16 && x.age<=20))
{
  /* print person */
}
```

I want just to print out these persons, but code prints non-compliant ages.

What is wrong with the condition?

Comment: Parentheses are your friend.

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: Dont add Thank you as an answer. Rather you can better upvote the answers provided to you if you have enough reputation for that.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
(x.name[0]=='s' || x.name[0]=='n') && (x.surname[0]=='s' || x.surname[0]=='n') && (x.age>=16 && x.age<=20)
```

Additional pair of () added. Also, You know that such a cumbersome statements are considered to be a really bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

Enclose each `||` section in brackets. Keep in mind `&&` has higher priority than `||`. Like so:

```
if((x.name[0]=='s' || x.name[0]=='n') &&
    (x.surname[0]=='s' || x.surname[0]=='n') && 
    (x.age>=16 && x.age<=20))
```

Splitting the code on several lines is not needed it just makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your missing parenthesis around the name and surname conditions

```
if((x.name[0]=='s' || x.name[0]=='n') && (x.surname[0]=='s' || x.surname[0]=='n') && (x.age>=16 && x.age<=20))
```

Answer (score 1):

On seeing the statement

```
if(x.name[0]=='s' ||
```

x.name[0]=='n' &&
   x.surname[0]=='s' ||
   x.surname[0]=='n' &&
   (x.age>=16 && x.age<=20))
compiler interpret it as

```
if(x.name[0]=='s' || (x.name[0]=='n' && x.surname[0]=='s') || 
  (x.surname[0]=='n' && x.age>=16) && x.age<=20))
```

The reason behind this is, logical operator `&&` has higher precedence than that of logical `||` operator. *What does it mean then?*
It means that the expression (sub-expression) get bound more closely to `&&` than that of `||`.
Take a small example to understand this

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void)
{
    int i = 1, j = 1, k = 1; 

    printf("%d ", i++ || ++j && ++k);  
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);  

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
1
2 1 1
```

On first look a novice may think that the output is wrong and it should be

```
1
2 1 2
```

by thinking that `i++ || ++j && ++k` is same as `(i++ || ++j) && ++k` but this is not true. Because of the higher precedence of `&&` over `||`, sub-expressions `j++` and `k++` bound to `&&` and it will be interpreted by the compiler as `i++ || (++j && ++k)`